# Low search - searching multiple children

Tags: low-search, related-entries

We currently perform searches and filters and we need to ALWAYS match results to a parent entry (lets assume entry ID 19826 - variable obviously).

We are using the native relationship field in EE 2.8.1 and low search 4.4.2

We need to use low search so that we can filter by category AND match keywords where the parent entry is 19826 (variable obviously).

An example query would be:

```
http://example.com/sandbox?child:related_field=19826
```

What we would like to do is search ALL channels for related child entries, is this possible, what would the typical query pattern for this be, can we combine multiples, for example:

```
http://example.com/sandbox?child:related_field=19826&child:another_related_field=19826
```

OR is there a way to simply search all entries that match our parent ID:

```
http://example.com/sandbox?child=19826
```

We've also tried multiple params as hidden fields in the form:

```
{exp:low_search:form result_page="/sandbox"}    
    <input type="hidden" name="child:related_field" value="19826">
    <input type="hidden" name="child:another_related_field" value="19826">      
    <button type="submit">Go</button>  
{/exp:low_search:form}
```

But no luck, this works if we ONLY have a single hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine any amount of filter parameters, including multiple [Relationships filters](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#relationships). Your second example would read like:

> Return entries that have both entry 19826 as a child via the `related_field` field *and* via the `another_related_field` field.

Right now, you can't consolidate the two parameters into a single one out of the box, but you could either use JS to populate the two parameters on form submit, or you could use an extension that uses the `low_search_pre_search` hook to populate the two parameters based on single one.

Comment: So, point one you made: combining params including multiple relationships. This doesn't seem to work. I've added example above.

Comment: If the search doesn't work as expected, please open [a GetSat thread](https://getsatisfaction.com/low) so we can debug this properly. Include your Template Debugger output to the report.

Comment: Thread opened https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/low-search-searching-multiple-related-children-parents?rfm=1